# Do AC voltages on datasheets refer to peak voltage or Vrms?

Tags: voltage, ac, datasheet

I'm attempting to find a relay to switch UK mains voltage (230Vrms); this gives a peak range of approximately 325V, -325V.

Consider something such as the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1717943.pdf) for this relay. It has a `rated voltage` of 250VAC and a `max switching voltage` of 277VAC, are these referring to peak voltage or rms voltages, and perhaps more generally is it a safe assumption that all AC voltages specifed on datasheets are always Vrms?

Comment: Unqualified AC voltages almost universally refer to RMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a value doesn't specify peak or p-p, an AC level is presumed to be RMS. 277VAC is an RMS value - that is how it should be interpreted.